# Excel IF statement in calculated field

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I am trying to create a calculated field that uses an IF statement in an Excel pivot table. I have a ratio (let's say x/y) and I need the actual returned value to be displayed if the ratio is >=0 and "<0" to be displayed if the ratio is less than zero. I have been trying the following:

```
=IF((x/y>0),(x/y),"<0")
```

It returns values for anything >0 but just gives VALUE! instead of returning "<0" for the ratio values that are less than zero. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure y is not 0? That should give you and error.

Comment: When y is 0, I get #DIV/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A calculated field in a Pivot Table cannot contain text, it can only contain numbers, because in a pivot table, the results of a calculated field are expected to be aggregate-able (through sum, for example).

The fact that `<0` is a text, it cannot be rendered as a number and thus results in a `#VALUE!` error.

You could however use conditional formatting on the Pivot Table to make all the values below zero **look** like `<0`:

[image]

Comment: The last number is supposed to be -6 by the way, and the ratio -1.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, I used the ratio without any `IF` in the calculated field because I'm accepting negative values.

Answer (score 0):

Just created my first Calculated Field in Excel with multiple `=If(And(...`

What I discovered is that `TEXT` is not permitted.

I created ranges depending on annualized sales, I assign them as the rank of 1,2,3,4...

Here's what it looked like:

```
If(Annualized>2000000,"1",If(AND(Annualized<2000000,Annualized>100000),"2",If(AND(Annualized<100000,Annualized>40000),"3",If(Annualized<40000,"4"))))
```

Comment: Don't forget your starting =